# Return value with try catch and finally

Tags: exception, try-catch

I need explanation for the below code.

```
public class ReturnValueFromTryCatchFinally
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(methodReturningValue());
    }

    static String methodReturningValue()
    {
        String s = null;
        try
        {
            s = "return value from try block";
            return s;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            s = s + "return value from catch block";
            return s;
        }
        finally
        {
            s = s + "return value from finally block";
        }
    }
}
```

My understanding is that finally block will be executed always and so that the value of s will be "return value from try block return value from finally block". 
But the above code gives me the value of s from try block. 
i.e; return value from try block. 
Why is that the value of s is returning from try block . As far as I know Finally block will be always executed. So won't the value of s be changed? Is there anything that I need to understand on Scope of the variable inside try, catch block.

This not only happens for string. It happens even when I return integer from the try block.

Answer (score 0):

**s** in the finally will be changed, but it will not affect what **try** returns.
When you change **s** in the **finally**, **s** just will point to another region in memory with a new text. But the **return** in the try already points to the text from **try** an this will not change.

May be it is easier to understand in this way. Strings in Java are immutable. If you change string variable, the previous text in the memory will not change. Instead, a new text is created a variable just "points" to the new text. In your **finally** block you just change where **s** points to, you cannot change the text of the **try** block.

If you had other type like List and in the **finally** block added or removed elements, this would affect what **try** returns.

I think you just simplified the code for readability. Right? Because in the **try** block no exception is possible and this code will not compile because of the **catch** block.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, Finally block will be always executed.
2. So won't the value of s be changed?
   Because String is immutable, so `s` in the try block is different from the `s` in the finally block. When `s = s + "return value from finally block";` new memory is allocated. The `return` in try block still refer to the old `s`.
3. You can try the same code but with mutable objects.

   ```
   static ArrayList<String> methodReturningValue()
   {
       ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>(5);

       try
       {
           arr.add("try");
           return arr;
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           arr.add("catch");
           return arr;
       }
       finally
       {
           arr.add("finally");
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Correct. I said above about the List. You have even illustrated this by code. Well done.

Answer (score 0):

@mentallurg

So if it works for string in such a way. Why is the following program also returning value from try

```
public class ReturnValueFromTryCatchFinally
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(methodReturningValue());
    }

    static int methodReturningValue()
    {
        int i = 0;

        try
        {
            i = 1;
            return i;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            i = 2;
        }
        finally
        {
            i = 3;
        }

        return i;
    }
}
```

We are passing integer. So should it not return 3 instead of 1.

Comment: @My Nguyen can you please check my answer below which has a example where I have tried return with integer type.

Comment: In the "try" block you have already passed value 1 to the return part. If you later change variable "i", it has no effect. May be it is easier to understand if you look at following:
try ...
  i = 1;
  doSomething(i);
finally ...
  i = 3;
Here the method "doSomething" obtains value 1. If you later change "i", it has no effect.
When "return" is executed, it is similar to this function call.
And again, your code is not compilable. I consider it only as simplification, assuming an exception is thrown in the try part.

Comment: @mentallurg Can you please give me with an example code.

Comment: Example of what? Example of the case when "finally" can change what is returned in the "try"? I have described it it the very first answer and "My Nguyen" have even provided the code for what I have described.

Comment: @Sushm For the sake of simplicity, you can understand that the return statement will be delayed after the finally block is executed but it still points to the assigned memory. In your second example, the last `return` statement will never be reached because after it execute the finally block, the program come back to the return statement in the try block and return. If you want to return 3, add the return in the finally block